# Why is my while loop printing out the same thing each time?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm sorry, I know this question is probably asked a million different times every day, but I truly can't find the answer I'm looking for. I'm a beginner in Java (I'm in college and learning a bunch of new languages), and my while loop is printing out the same thing every time.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is the loan amount? ");
        int amount = scanner.nextInt();
        int x = 1;
        //your code goes here
        while (x < 6){
            System.out.println("Month " +x+ ":");

            int percent = (amount / 10);
            System.out.println("Payment: 10 percent of " +amount+ " = " +percent);

            int rAmt = amount - percent;
            System.out.println("Remaining amount: " +rAmt);

            x++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What would you expect to be different?

Comment: What is updating the **amount** variable? Step through your code with your IDE debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is that you never actually change `amount` after doing your calculations inside the while loop. What I think you want to do, is to set `amount = rAmt;`, which would produce the following code. This will cause the amount to be decreased by 10% each iteration, and this new value carried forward.

```
...
//your code goes here
        while (x < 6){
            System.out.println("Month " +x+ ":");

            int percent = (amount / 10);
            System.out.println("Payment: 10 percent of " +amount+ " = " +percent);

            int rAmt = amount - percent;
            System.out.println("Remaining amount: " +rAmt);
            amount = rAmt; 
            x++;
        }
...
```

Comment: You could actually remove the `rAmt` variable if you want, and instead assign `amount = amount - percent;`, but be sure to update the print statement along with it.